# A puzzle in my mind about association bonus

Tags: discussion

Stack Exchange users with at least 200 reputation on one site will get a one-time association bonus of 100 whenever they join a new site on the network. This new user whose profile I noticed just today presents an interesting puzzle regarding upvotes and reputation points:

https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users/6037/alina-cretu?__=869409032

She has been a member at Stack Overflow for about 2 months and joined IPS.SE 2 days ago. Now seen to have 101 points on SO and same on a few other SE sites.

She has written 3 answers and received 31 upvotes on IPS, which is a very good start here. Which adds up to 311 points but she has 411. That indicates an association bonus.

So this was what I did not understand:

If she has less than 200 points on SO and never posted a Q or A there, nor anywhere else until very recently, then how did she come over to IPS with an association bonus?

---

After reading the help topics page here on [reputation -  'association bonus'](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) this is a possible solution that suggests itself:

She did not join IPS.SE **with an** association bonus from SO. Once she reached 201 points here, she automatically got 100 association bonus each to SO, IPS and those other sites. So 201 became 301 here and has now reached 411 with further upvotes.

Is that the correct understanding of how association bonus works? If so please confirm or else correct. Good explanatory answers about the process are most welcome.

Answer (score 3):

You've answered your own question.

You get the association bonus on **all** sites, including the one you hit 200 reputation on. So as soon as you hit 200, you get a bump up to 300.

You can see this happened if you look at her [reputation history](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users/6037/alina-cretu?tab=reputation).

The events are out of order but she earned 200 reputation on 9/20 and was awarded the association bonus at 22:34, the same time as her last upvote for the day.

Comment: I joined my second SE site ELL only after reaching 2000+ points on ELU; that means I didn't experience the 'bump up' from 201 to 301, and didn't notice/ understand the actual bump at maybe 2200 so I was not sure that a member gets +100 **for the first site as well** as all subsequent sites. Thanks a lot for the very quick confirmation and the link, @Catija.